# Disk errors persist after cloning

Tags: chkdsk, clonezilla

I have an Asus Laptop that came with a Seagate HDD. Chkdsk could not fix some errors on that original disk, so I decided to buy a new one: a Western Digital with the exact same size (500 GB).

Then I used Clonezilla to clone the old disk to the new one, removed the old one, and booted with no problems.

However, running chkdisk in the **new** disk also displays some errors, and running chkdisk /r /f won't fix them!

Is it possible that clonezilla clones also the errors, and in such a way that those errors are still unfixable on the target disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not probable that Clonezilla copied physical errors from one disk to another; however, it's more probable that your controller in your laptop is beginning to fail.

Or, another probable solution is that you have folders that are deeply nested inside one another (like music folders) and chkdsk is having a hard time with them.

Chkdsk is an old utility and in not infallible.

[Read here for more](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=315688).

Can you possibly provide some of the error that you are getting from chkdsk?

Comment: I think you are correct. It turns out that the chkdsk output is different every time it runs. A few hours ago it was refering some files buried somewere in a deep temporary folder.

Right now the output is: The BITMAP attribute of the master file table (MFT) is incorrect, so I better focus on that.